# Most efficent way to mount static files over network ubuntu/linux?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, mount, read-only

I am building a diskless network boot setup with ubuntu on both sides, which requires to mount an read-only system /root.

What is the most performant/efficient way to mount 106013 static files in 4.4GB over linux?

Things I tried / am thinking about:

- NFSv3 performance was slow even when in tmpfs on server
- DavFs http overhead? Might be fast with good webserver and caching
- remote block device?

Comment: You may try iSCSI boot with PXE or better use FCoE (Fibre Channel over Ethernet)

Comment: I tried NFSv4 with parallel RW in tempfs, Performance increased beyond network limitations.